# My hotpot has a stand attached to it

Tags: cookware

So my dad bought a hot pot. I know what you cook in a hot pot. It says in the bottom "Hot Pot." But the bottom isn't what I expected. Normally, a hotpot is in a bowl shape. But this one has somewhat a stand. It's like a small inverted bowl attached to the bottom and it keeps the hotpot still. It's hollow. Is this normal? How do I use this hotpot? Do I just place the hotpot with it's stand on top of a stove?

Comment: Have you a photo? Maybe a link to where we can see that model online?

Comment: can you link to a picture?  I've seen some that have a stand, but have an opening to insert sterno or similar

Comment: [Here](http://www.pradeepstainless.com/Products/81/shayna.jpg) is the closest resemblance. Same brand. Just couldn't find mine. But it's very close in resemblance. Can't take picture right now sorry.

Comment: Found it. [This](http://www.pradeepstainless.com/Products/83/sp_jumbo.jpg) is our hotpot. The "Stand" is not much visible in the pic. But it's very much like the first pic I linked.

Comment: The "stand" is, estimate, 1 or 1 1/2 inches tall.

Comment: Does it have a power cord attached? (In the US a 'Hot Pot' would have an internal heating element that plugs in. This appears to be closer to what I would call a 'chaffing dish'.)

Comment: Just atop a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you know what to cook in a Hot Pot and confirm that this product is identified on the body as a 'Hot Pot', but I think the issue may be that 'Hot Pot' means different things in different cuisines.
Where I come from a Hot pot is a lamb, potato and onion dish which is slow cooked in an oven. In East Asia it is a soup that simmers on the table while you cook morsels of ingredients in the broth. In India/South Asia, it is a vessel designed to keep cooked food warm until it is needed some hours later.

I suspect you were looking for a vessel suitable for the East Asian Hot Pot but what you have is an Indian Hot Pot.

This [short advertising video](https://youtu.be/3nPU-nIttdU) includes a model called a ‘dome hot pot’ which looks very similar to the one you have., and the video description call these ‘insulated casseroles’.

I can’t find explicit product details for an insulated hot pot with a ‘foot’ design, but insulated or double walled hot pots are for keeping food warm, **not** for cooking it. As an example here’s a Q&A for a flat based version on amazon.co.uk[image: screenshot showing amazon customer explaining how the insulation in his hot pot expanded and split the pot when he put it on the stove]

Also from [Attila brand hot pot on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/SQ-Professional-Thermal-Insulated-Stainless/dp/B01M71F5EG):

> Do not place the Attila Hot Pot on hot surfaces or near open fire

So, if I am correct and you have an insulated casserole, I would recommend you only use it to keep food warm, and do not place it on a stove.

Indicators that it is an insulated casserole/hot pot would be:
- Indian origin
- lock/clip lid to keep food tightly sealed
- thick side walls and lid indicating two layers of metal with vacuum or insulation between.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It suggests that the device the OP *has* is **not** a cooking vessel.

Comment: But OP asks "How do I use it?" Not "What is it?" Based on the links provided by OP it is almost certainly a '_cooking vessel_'. Whether it is self contained (has it's own heating element like the 'Hot Pots' common in the US) or it's more of stove top device (most likely from what I know now, looking at similar items from the same manufacturer)

Comment: As I think the answer is ‘You **can’t use it** for what you intend because it’s the wrong thing’ I’ve expanded my answer to include more info on the Indian food storage/serving vessel called a Hot Pot. You will see that they do look almost identical to cooking pots, but they aren’t suitable for that use. I’m sorry if my original description of a vessel to ‘keep cooked food warm’ didn’t make that sufficiently explicit.

Comment: No. This answered my question. I did not know there were such different hot pots per cuisine. Thank you!

Comment: My question had a "how to use it" but only because it stemmed from the assumption that this was the hotpot that other asian countries use.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this stand is to allow continously heating the (already heated) hotpot after it has been brought to the table, by putting a small heat source (eg an alcohol burner, sterno, a hexamine tablet ... ) beneath it. This way, the hotpot is kept hot.

Comment: The height of the stand and lack of mention of any air holes in it makes this seem slightly improbable. It seems more likely that it is intended to be the sort of hot pot that you prewarm with water before filling and it just keeps food a little warm at table.

Comment: In which case, the stand is to ensure there is heat insulating air beneath it?

Comment: I can't put a small heat source below because there really is no air holes nor is it high enough.